# Spring JPA Saving Parent Object is not Saving Child Object - Resolved (at end of comment)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, plsql, spring-data-jpa

I have a csv file that has a list of employees and projects information (each employee having multiple projects).
I upload the file, parse the csv and build a parent-child relationship -> Employee and Projects respectively and save it to Database.

Below is my Employee Entity class (I tried the commented part but no luck)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String empId;
    @NotNull
    private String department;

    //@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "transcript", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //tried didn't work
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Project> projects;

    public Employee(String name, String empId, String department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

Below is my Project Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String projectName;
    private String projectCode;
        private Instant projectStartDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Employee employee;

    public Project(String name, String code, Instant time) {
        this.projectName = name;
        this.projectCode = code;
        this.projectStartDate = time;
    }
}
```

This is where I am trying to save my Employee object:

```
@Transactional
    public void uploadEmployees(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
//calls csv helper that does all the parsing and brings into Employee model object format
            Set<Employess> employees = CSVHelper.csvToEmployess(file.getInputStream(), "2");
            employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
            System.out.println("I processed all the records of cdv into java");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }catch (Exception e ){
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This above method throws :

```
2022-09-11T22:30:08.438-05:00 ERROR 63321 --- [nio-8086-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "employee_id" of relation "projects" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (6, p1, 123, 0184-06-08T01:07:47Z, null).
```

If I change the id generation type to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) : I get the below exception:

```
2022-09-12T00:55:09.465-05:00  WARN 73014 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2022-09-12T00:55:09.465-05:00 ERROR 73014 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy133.saveAll(Unknown Source)
```

Just before executing saveAll method,I tried looking how my employees list looks like using debugger and it looks as below :

```
  Employee(id=0, name="test", empId="4511504557911789", department="JJ967W"
        projects=[
                Project(id=0, projectName="p1", projectCode="123", projectStartDate="0184-06-08T01:07:47Z", employee=null),
                Project(id=0, projectName="p2", projectCode="345", projectStartDate="0184-06-08T01:07:47Z", employee=null)
                ]
        )
```

I am thinking `employee=null` makes sense because it was not saved to DB yet.

Please help me out in what I am missing here that is causing this to break.
Thank you very much for taking time in providng help.

**** UPDATED ****

Adding the part where I am adding parsing CSV and building Employee and Project objects

```
public static Set<Employee> csvToTranscripts(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
             CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader,
                     CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());) {
            Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
            List<CSVRecord> csvRecordsList = csvParser.getRecords();
            Employee employee = null;
            List<String> empIds = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Project> projects = null;
            //iterate through list and create project list for new emp_id
            for(CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecordsList){
                if(employees.isEmpty() || !empIds.contains(csvRecord.get("EMP_ID"))){
                    employee = new Employee(
                            csvRecord.get("NAME"),
                            csvRecord.get("EMP_ID"),
                            csvRecord.get("DEPARTMENT")
                    );
                    empIds.add(csvRecord.get("EMP_ID")); //this is mainly to check for unique emp id
                    projects = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                Project project = new Project(csvRecord.get("NAME"),
                        csvRecord.get("CODE"),
                        formatToInstant(csvRecord.get("TIME")) );
                project.setEmployee(employee);//setting employee to project here
                projects.add(project);
                employee.setProjects(projects); //setting projects list to employee here
                employees.add(employee);
            }
            return employees;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail to parse CSV file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

************ RESOLVED ******************
Thanks everyone for help. Setting employee to project resolved the issue. what a dumb I am !!!

```
 project.setEmployee(employee);
```

Comment: `employee=null` is the employee null or just the ID?

Comment: You have a bi-directional relationship, you need to set the `Employee` on the `Project` else it won't save anything. So if you add a `Project` to the `Employee` call `setEmployee(this);` on the `Project` (or when setting the `List` which is actually a bad idea). Additionally using `@Data` for entities is a bad idea as it generates wrong `equals` and `hashCode` (for JPA at least).

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : Yes. The employee is coming as null.

Comment: @M.Deinum
I added the code which parses the csv and build the Employee and Project objects. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Also, I read about `@Data` with `Entity` and what you said makes sense. Thanks for the tip. I will clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to comment by @M.Deinum - declare a method like this in your Employee class and use it to add a project to an employee ensuring the bidirectional relationship is kept in sync

```
    public void addProject(Project project) {
        if (projects == null) {
            projects = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        project.setEmployee(this);
        projects.add(project);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I shared the code where I am building objects. I am creating the Project list and setting those to employee...something like Employee.setProjects(projects) while building Employee.

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking employee=null makes sense because it was not saved to DB yet.

This is wrong. If you save an item with bi-directional relationship then you cannot have a case when an orphan `Project` exists without an `Employee`. So before calling any `CrudRepository.save*()` you must make sure that all `projects` reference some `Employee`.

Often in such cases when you add projects to employee you do it like:

```java
// method of Employee class
public void addAll(Projects projects) {
  for (Project : projects) {
    project.setEmployee(this);
  }
  this.projects.addAll(projects);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I shared the code where I am building objects. I am setting the Employee.setPorjects while building Employee.

Comment: So you should accept either my answer, or the one below, basically both are about the same.